# c# - Redirect on button click produces 403 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect, iframe

I have a form inside on iframe. When the user clicks on the submit button inside the form, I want to call the Submit_Click function. Inside Submit_Click, I have some validation checks. If the validations pass, I want to redirect to another page.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some validation code...

    Response.StatusCode = 307;
    Response.AddHeader("Location", MY_REDIRECT_URL);
}
```

Right now when Submit_Click executes and the page redirects, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I'm not sure why I'm getting the 403 error. When I put the response header in the page load event handler function, the page redirects without any problems.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 307;
        Response.AddHeader("Location", MY_REDIRECT_URL);
    }
}
```

How can I get the page to redirect successfully in the Submit_Click function?

Comment: Works fine here. What browser did you use?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to useResponse.Redirect("Page.aspx");

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some validation code...

```
Response.StatusCode = 307;
Response.Redirect(MY_REDIRECT_URL);
```

}

Comment: I tried Response.Redirect and got a 405 Method not allowed error.